Are all the “needs and wants” of the universe already thought of?
Technology is always progressing and science appears to be bottomless. But is there a limit to the needs and wants of a living being?
Our ancient ancestors weren’t that much different than us. I’m sure some of them wanted to fly like birds and humanity eventually achieved that.
It is also pretty likely that an ancient human at one point pondered how great it would be if he could vanish from a location and then appear at another one instantly, without having to take time to travel. This is called teleportation. We don’t know how to do that (yet?) but the concept has existed for all time.
Will humans ever have a need or want that hasn’t been thought of yet? Something we currently can’t imagine wanting or needing?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Can we imagine something we can't currently imagine?

My great grandfather didnt know how much he missed the charms of social networks. And his great grandfather likewise for electricity.  I could multiply this list a 100 fold. So could you. What's the point?

Right, telegraph, radiotelegraph, analog radio, television, computers, networks, online shopping and media, now AI... Probably not what Michael Faraday imagined while developing the principles of electromagnetic induction 200 years ago. James Watt might be a bit surprised by jet airplanes and rockets.

Each new technology creates new needs associated with the technology. The introduction of horse riding made people want a more secure way to sit on a horse, leading to the stirrup. The introduction of spears led to people wanting a way to throw spears further, leading to the invention of spear throwers. The invention of the computer led people to want to play games on the computer, leading to the invention of the graphics card. The patent office has a long list of solutions to problems that were fairly new when the problem was solved, especially software patents.
Alternatively, in a more general sense, human desires have not changed in all that time. They still want love and/or respect, they still chafe at restrictions like time, space, and gravity, and have dreams of overcoming them. They still have enemies and dream of god-like powers to defeat them. In that more general sense, not much has changed.

I think there is only one need and desire of all life, and that is to survive, and if life can achieve eternal life, then all other needs and desires will disappear.
I don't know why life takes survival as its most basic need, but we see that it is precisely because life cannot live forever that there is such a long list of realistic cause-and-effect relationships: It is because of the impossibility that life has the need to reproduce, it is because of the need to reproduce that it has the need to expand, it is because of the need to expand that it has the need to strengthen itself, it is because of the need to strengthen itself that it has the need to evolve in different directions, It is because of the need to evolve in different directions that we have sexual reproduction, DNA and various organs, it is because of sexual reproduction, DNA and various organs that we have the ability to see and hear, and it is because of the ability to see and hear that we have different perceptual abilities and the ability to understand the world... .
I could extend this chain of cause and effect indefinitely, but it is a strong indication that if life did not have the need for eternal life, all the other needs and desires of life would not arise.
Of course, we can also set some conditions for the reverse inference: if the Earth's environment is comfortable enough, then life can achieve immortality from the day it is born, there is no need to reproduce. If the Earth were large enough and abundant enough, life would not have to compete and kill each other for resources. If life had begun with an encyclopedic bank of experience embedded in the genes, there would have been no need to learn, no need to acquire experience at the cost of death. If man had wings to fly freely in the sky, he would not have been misled for thousands of years by the absurd theory that the Earth is the center of the universe... .
There are so many flaws in life that if these problems had not existed in the first place, the history of life would have been completely different. But these flaws are real, and it took 3.8 billion years of tortuous history for life to evolve the way it is now. Therefore, we can say that the needs and desires of life are not formed spontaneously, but are born to compensate for these defects, and gradually appear in order to resist natural selection. If there were an Almighty God who would solve all our problems at once, all our needs and desires would disappear in an instant.
So the only ultimate question for all of life is: why should we make survival our ultimate goal?
This question also leads to an even more interesting question: if the ultimate goal of survival is given to us by some unknown will, what is its purpose?

"why life takes survival as its most basic need": because if you're dead you can't do much of anything else? Sine Qua Non

@Scott Rowe Both a rabbit and a rock are made of many elementary particles, so we can call both the rabbit and the rock particle complexes. Is that okay? Then there are two questions that extend here:


Do both the rabbit and the stone have the will not to disintegrate themselves as particles?


The rabbit disintegrates as a particle complex and can be called dead. So what should the stone be called when it disintegrates as a particle?



Inanimate things don't die, and they don't much worry about it either. I was agreeing with you.

@Scott Rowe  Non-living things don't care about disintegrating. So what is unique about life is that it has the will to try not to disintegrate itself as a consortium of particles, and what is unique about human beings is that sometimes we choose to disintegrate ourselves.
What do you think it means to go down to the level of elementary particles again? Why do the same particles, the stone, the rabbit, and the human, have such markedly different attitudes toward their own disintegration?

Because they can. I believe that you are reaching for a teleological explanation. I certainly understand if that is true. I used to do that, but for me, it fell flat. Humans consider suicide because it is a thing they can do, so eventually someone will have the thought. Rabbits apparently don't have this thought, but they do work for self preservation because they can, and the ones that didn't died off. Kangaroos live in a different environment and don't seem as bent on survival as rabbits. Stones can't consider or act, so, they do not. No great story here.

@Scott Rowe If you only look at the field of life, it seems that there is no good story. But if we look at the most microscopic particles and the most macroscopic universe, the story might be wonderful.
Because the universe is evolving toward maximum entropy, there is evidence for time. But as a part of the universe, why would life strive to maintain a low-entropy state? Isn't it interesting that this will is so humble and yet so strong?

@Scott Rowe I am not entirely in favor of teleology, because the first cause of the universe is unknowable, so we cannot use incomplete causal chains to deduce the ultimate purpose of the universe, which makes no sense. Nor am I entirely in favor of the heat death theory, because it has a fatal flaw: it stands at a very short point in time to predict the state and outcome of the universe over an almost infinite period of time, which is undoubtedly absurd.
But it is these contradictions that make the question of why life has the will to live interesting, or at least open to discussion.
